# PHP Paypal SDK with Payment Data Transfer

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

In Paypal developer account I have configured Payment Data Transfer settings and acquired Identity Token. (Return URL is also added)
I am using PayPal PHP SDK.
Which class and where in PHP code I can pass Identity Token?